# There are four item possibilities: A, B, C, D (there's unlimited supply of each item). In how many ways can you take 7 items?

Tags: combinatorics

Basically let's say there's 4 types of cakes: You have to buy 7 cakes. In how many different ways can you choose the 7 cakes?

Comment: The *general* problem can be solved using Stars and Bars (please see Wikipedia).

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own efforts to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Andre was referring to this article on [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition).

Comment: At the very least, please clarify what you mean by a 'way'.

Answer (score 0):

For the first cake, you have 4 options, for the second, 4 options again, and so on... 4x4x4....

Comment: You misunderstood the question.  The question amounts to asking how many solutions are there to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 7$ in the nonnegative integers.  See this Wikipedia article on [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition).

Comment: As @N.F.Taussig has commented, this "Answer" is not likely helpful. You are looking at ordered ways and counting AAABBBB and BABABAB as different. Both result in 3 cakes of type A and 4 of type B. It seems likely the person who wrote the question does not intend to count them as different. At least, the latter interpretation leads to a more interesting problem.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo, you are probably right. I interpreted 'way' considering the order is important.

Comment: But without clarification from OP as to the context, we are $all$ only guessing.